# Multiline Textinputs in Workspace Add Ons only single line when first opening the Add On

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace-add-ons

I have developed a Google Workspace Add On in Apps Script with a text input. I would like to display it multiline because the value I set to the text input is quite long.

```
  let input_txt = CardService.newTextInput()
  .setTitle("test")
  .setValue("A long text which requieres that the text input is multiline because the text doesnt fit in a single line")
  .setFieldName("input_txt")
  .setMultiline(true)
  
  let Section = CardService.newCardSection()
  .addWidget(input_txt)

  let card = CardService.newCardBuilder()
  .addSection(Section);

  return card.build();
```

If have set `.setMultiline(true)` but every time I open the Add on for the first time in a document the text input is only a single line. When I refresh the Add on it appears multi line.

Is that a bug of Google or did I use some wrong code?

[image]

Comment: Does this happen with incognito windows or other browsers and have you tried with different users?

Comment: Yes, I have tried it with different users, different browsers and also in incognito window.

Comment: If [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75980294/17926478) answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon). By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [How to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce the same behavior and it seems that someone else has reported this in the past, you can check that [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/u/3/issues/177648333). You can add a comment in the same thread to give more details regarding the behavior or you can try opening a new issue tracker through [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/u/3/issues/new?component=642720&template=1392206). What I noticed while testing, if you continue typing in the text input then it shows multi lines.

A good recommendation based on [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/guides/workspace-style#writing_style):

> **Writing style**
> You shouldn’t need to write much. Most actions should be made clear
> through iconography, layout, and short labels...
>
> When writing UI text:
>
> - Use sentence case (especially for buttons, labels, and card actions).
> - Prefer short, simple text without jargon or acronyms.

Instead of using a long text in the text input label, enter a short text and the description of the text input can be added as a hint.

Using your sample I tested the following:

```
let input_txt = CardService.newTextInput()
      .setTitle("test")
      .setValue("Enter text here")
      .setHint("A long text which requieres that the text input is multiline because the text doesnt fit in a single line")
      .setFieldName("input_txt")
      .setMultiline(true)
```

When you open the Add-On it would look like this and you can add long text to the text input as it is multi line.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Thats a hint and I hope others can use it. For me it is not suitable. 
And by the way, long strings (like URLs) are not getting wrapped in hints or decorated text elements so the line just ends with [...] which is not the best case, too
So all in all for me it seems like this is a bug